# Why would NSURL Connection Received Data contain bytes, but on conversion to NSString, the string is Null?

Tags: ios, encoding, nsstring, nsurlconnection, nsdata

I have tried a lot of other solutions from other posts, but have not successfully got a string from my received data. Except I am running almost a replica on another file and it works 100% of the time. It even gets the data from the exact same php file.

```
+ (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

    [imagesTableData appendData:data];
    NSString *dataStringImages = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:imagesTableData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    receivedDataImages = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",receivedDataImages,dataStringImages];

}

+ (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"%lu -- %@",(unsigned long)[imagesTableData length],receivedDataImages);
}
```

NSLog Output: 14938 -- (null)

[image]

I have fixed my issue by changing the encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding to encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding. See my fix for didReceiveData below:

```
+ (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

    [imagesTableData appendData:data];
    NSString *dataStringImages = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:imagesTableData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    receivedDataImages = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",receivedDataImages,dataStringImages];

}
```

Now I am left with why was this the fix? Let me explain what is making this so perplexing to me. I have two different but similar utility files that I am using to receive data for parsing and I then in put them into a database.

The issue is that both files connect to the same PHP file and that PHP file outputs data the exact same way with different amounts of data. Why would one need an encoding of "NSUTF8StringEncoding" and the other "NSASCIIStringEncoding"?

See my code and the related data output below for each utility file.

**Utility File A**

```
+ (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

    [placesTableData appendData:data];
    NSString *dataStringPlaces = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:placesTableData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    receivedDataPlaces = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",receivedDataPlaces,dataStringPlaces];

}
```

**Utility Data A**

```
MERRYMAN|Merryman Performing Arts Center|LOC|40.698903|-99.085779|||Mention this coupon when ordering for 20% off tickets at the Merryman Performing Arts Center.|308-698-8297||http://www.merrymancenter.org|225 West 22nd Street Kearney, NE 68845||0000-00-00 00:00:00|0000-00-00 00:00:00|0|2014-07-16 21:29:51~~
```

**Utility File B**

```
+ (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

    [imagesTableData appendData:data];
    NSString *dataStringImages = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:imagesTableData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    receivedDataImages = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",receivedDataImages,dataStringImages];

}
```

**Utility Output B**

```
WSGFFJKM|LIPS Printing Service 25% Off|LIPSNewCustomerAd2014_KearneyApp.jpg||LIPSPRINTING2|2014-07-16 23:46:07~~
```

If you have any input as to how or if I should rewrite my question, please suggest in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) for `initWithData:encoding:`:

> Returns nil if the initialization fails for some reason (for example
>   if data does not represent valid data for encoding).

Double check that your data is of the correct encoding or a string at all. You might want to put off converting the data to string until *after* the connection is finished loading as well.

Comment: Wouldn't he have to wait until all the data is downloaded to be able to view it? What he's doing is trying to see the data mid download. Im wondering what will happen if he places the data to NSString method in connection did finish downloading

Comment: Maybe. It all depends on if the data downloaded maps cleanly to the encoding. With UTF 8 if all characters are single bytes it should work fine to convert at any point. If a multi-byte character gets split it could cause issues. Considering this is a list of images, I doubt that the data is useful until the whole thing is downloaded anyways. I did go ahead and add that suggestion.

Comment: In the php file I have used "header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');" with no change.

Comment: @Esko918 Essentially what I am doing inside the didReceiveData method is appending the data to my string receivedDataImages. In my method connectionDidFinishLoading is where I output the full string and total bytes which you can see in my NSLog output.

Comment: @Cedric Right, but building the string as you go does two things: 1. It presents a risk that you will not be able to convert the data to a string. And 2. You're throwing away a lot of work that you may not need to do. If you `connection:didReceiveData:` is called 100 times, you're attempting to create 100 strings and only really using 1.

Comment: @Esko918 For the sake of trying I took the data to string method and put it before the NSLog and I got the same results.

Comment: @Cedric, I'd check that your data is, in fact, a string. Try saving it to a file and examining the contents.

Comment: Please take a look at my edit with the image I have put up. I am hoping that will answer any questions of the data being passed. Let me know if this still does not authenticate that the data is a string.

Comment: Well i never tried to display data mid download before, i actually didn't know it was possible but as @BergQuester says if its UTF 8 and single byte characters you actually can display data incrementally opposed to having to wait for the full amount of data to download. Thanks for the tip

Comment: I selected you answer as I changed the encoding from NSUTF8StringEncoding to NSASCIIStringEncoding. But what is not understood on my part is why. Please see my edits and if you can elaborate on your answer some more that would be most helpful in the future for others.

Comment: Good question, especially since, to my understanding, ASCII is just a subset of UTF-8. What does the http headers say the encoding is?